# Video recorded from EAGLView is flipped when uploaded to youtube

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es-2.0, avmutablecomposition, google-api-objc-client

In my ios app, I am trying to record video of the content of EAGLView(There is no Camera involvement). I have no problem recording the video. 
After recording I have to add few sound tracks to the video and then have to share this video to Youtube and facebook. My problem is that the video is okay when I play it on iphone or on mac but when I upload this video to youtube (using Youtube Data Api v3), the video is vertically inverted or upside down.

I guess I need to rotate the frame in video before uploading but I don't know how to do that.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

The code I am using to add audio tracks to the video is below:

```
-(void)prepareVideoForPath:(NSString *)videoPath usingAudio:(NSArray *)audioArray andOutputPath:(NSString *)exportPath{


NSDictionary *optionsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey];

NSURL *videoUrl=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];

AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:videoUrl options:optionsDictionary];

AVAssetTrack *FirstAssetTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
CGAffineTransform firstTransform = FirstAssetTrack.preferredTransform;
AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];


//VideoTrack

AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration) ofTrack:FirstAssetTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
[compositionVideoTrack setPreferredTransform:firstTransform];


//Audio Track

AVMutableCompositionTrack *audioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

CMTime audioStartTime = kCMTimeZero;
for (NSURL *audioURL in audioArray) {
    AVURLAsset *audioAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:audioURL options:optionsDictionary];
    [audioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset.duration) ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:audioStartTime error:nil];
    audioStartTime = CMTimeAdd(audioStartTime, audioAsset.duration);
}


AVAssetExportSession* _assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];


NSURL *exportUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:exportPath];

_assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;

NSLog(@"file type %@",_assetExport.outputFileType);

_assetExport.outputURL = exportUrl;

_assetExport.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;

[_assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:

 ^(void ) {

     // your completion code here

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         NSLog(@"Mixing complete");

     });

 }

 ];
```

}

Comment: I want to know how do you record video of the content that is displayed in GLKView.
By searching forums, I know if I can get a series of images, I can render them into an video.

Do you get images first and render them into an video? 
If so, how do you get the images?
Do you capture the screen periodically or in some other ways?
 
Can you give me any clues?
Thank you!

Comment: You can create video by creating a series of images using glReadPixels() but it is very expensive to use. Another methods is using Frame Buffer objects(FBO) which is very fast and efficient. I succeeded in creating video using FBOs but messed the content display on the screen i.e. nothing get displayed on the screen, every thing was going to video. I am not much comfortable in openGLES. I am currently using [**Everyplay SDK**](https://developers.everyplay.com/) to record video of my GLKView.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try Everyplay SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found it how to rotate a video.

Here is the code:

```
-(void)fixVideoOrientationForURL:(NSURL *)videoURL andOutputPath:(NSString *)exportPath{


    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:videoURL options:@{ AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey:@YES }];

    AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *instruction = nil;
    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *layerInstruction = nil;

    CGAffineTransform transform;

AVAssetTrack *assetVideoTrack = nil;
AVAssetTrack *assetAudioTrack = nil;
// Check if the asset contains video and audio tracks
if ([[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] count] != 0) {
    assetVideoTrack = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo][0];
}
if ([[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] count] != 0) {
    assetAudioTrack = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio][0];
}

CMTime insertionPoint = kCMTimeZero;
NSError *error = nil;


// Step 1
// Create a composition with the given asset and insert audio and video tracks into it from the asset

AVMutableComposition *mutableComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

    // Insert the video and audio tracks from AVAsset
    if (assetVideoTrack != nil) {
        AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [mutableComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
        [compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [asset duration]) ofTrack:assetVideoTrack atTime:insertionPoint error:&error];
    }
    if (assetAudioTrack != nil) {
        AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTrack = [mutableComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
        [compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [asset duration]) ofTrack:assetAudioTrack atTime:insertionPoint error:&error];
    }

// Step 2
// Translate the composition to compensate the movement caused by rotation (since rotation would cause it to move out of frame)
// Rotate transformation
    transform = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, assetVideoTrack.naturalSize.height);

// Step 3
// Set the appropriate render sizes and rotational transforms


    // Create a new video composition
    AVMutableVideoComposition *mutableVideoComposition = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
    mutableVideoComposition.renderSize = CGSizeMake(assetVideoTrack.naturalSize.width,assetVideoTrack.naturalSize.height);
    mutableVideoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);

    // The rotate transform is set on a layer instruction
    instruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
    instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [mutableComposition duration]);
    layerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:(mutableComposition.tracks)[0]];
    [layerInstruction setTransform:t2 atTime:kCMTimeZero];

// Step 4
// Add the transform instructions to the video composition
instruction.layerInstructions = @[layerInstruction];
mutableVideoComposition.instructions = @[instruction];


    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:[mutableComposition copy] presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];

exportSession.videoComposition = mutableVideoComposition;
exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:exportPath];
exportSession.outputFileType=AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;

[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void){

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            switch (exportSession.status) {
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
                    NSLog(@"writing complete");


                    break;
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                    NSLog(@"Failed:%@",exportSession.error);
                    break;
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
                    NSLog(@"Canceled:%@",exportSession.error);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        });

}];
}
```